# How to make linked list function return specific class object instead of "Object" in Java?

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I'm new to java. unvisited and visited are linked lists with elements that are Node class objects, how can I make this method return a Node class object instead of an "Object"? I need to be able to use the output from this function to move onto the next unvisited puzzle state but I can't access the puzzle state within the Node class, and if I try to make the function return a Node it says it's a type mismatch (even though every single element in the list is a Node...). Please help, thank you.

```
/**
 * Removes last visited puzzle state from unvisited queue and adds it to the visited list. 
 * Returns next puzzle state to visit from unvisited queue. 
 */
public Object nextState() {
    // if unvisited is empty, return null (no solution)
    if (unvisited.size() == 0) { 
        return null;
    }
    // remove visited node from unvisited list & add to beginning of visited list
    visited.addFirst(unvisited.removeFirst());
    // visit next unvisited node
    Object first = unvisited.getFirst();
    return first;
}
```

Comment: Show us how you are doing your cast.

Comment: Return the datatype of unvisited before you cast it to object

Comment: Do you have problems with the return type of the linked list? Show us how you initialize unvisited.

Answer (score 1):

change the return type of the function to Node instead of object like so

```
public Node nextState() {
// if unvisited is empty, return null (no solution)
    if (unvisited.size() == 0) { 
        return null;
    }
    // remove visited node from unvisited list & add to beginning of visited list
    visited.addFirst(unvisited.removeFirst());
    // visit next unvisited node
    Node first = unvisited.getFirst();
    return first;
```

Comment: unvisited.getFirst() still gives me a type mismatch that it can't convert from Object to Node with this code...any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post all of your code so i can see everything that is there so i can assist you further

Answer (score 0):

```
public Node nextState() {
// if unvisited is empty, return null (no solution)
    if (unvisited.size() == 0) { 
        return null;
    }
    // remove visited node from unvisited list & add to beginning of visited list
    visited.addFirst(unvisited.removeFirst());
    // visit next unvisited node
    Object first = unvisited.getFirst();
    if(first instance of Node){
        return (Node) first;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is your `unvisited.getFirst()` is returning an object of type **Object**. So you need to cast it to Node type and return it. '**instance of**' is a preventive measure, you can avoid it if you think it always returns an objet of type Node

Comment: If you set the generic type to Node, it should return a Node, not an Object, dosen't it?
`LinkedList<Node> unvisited = new LinkedList<Node>` should fix it

Comment: Sorry, forgot the method brackets and can't edit my post...
`LinkedList<Node> unvisited = new LinkedList<Node>()` should fix it

Comment: @Maze that was not in OP's question. So did not refer to that solution. Its great since it worked

Comment: @pratim_b Searched for the best solution and casting is not really the best. His question was what will solve his type mismatch, so it is a solution. Btw, it won't work because `instanceof` operator is one word.